# ORACLE SQL ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined When making query

Tags: oracle

I want to make query data, there are taken from several tables, and when I tried to execute my query SQL, error information from SQL has appeared.

> ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined. 00918. 00000 -  "column ambiguously defined"

```
SELECT t1.inst_no,
       t1.itm_cd,
       t3.itm_nm,
       t1.prod_loc_cd,
       DECODE(t1.bom_ptn,
             1,'1 : IM',
             2,'2 : SUBCON',
             3,'3 : SW',
             4,'4 : TRIAL',
             5,'5 : CUSTOM'
       ) bom_ptn,
       t1.prod_schd_qty,
       t1.mld_br_no,
       t4.ins_ts,
       sum(t4.act_qty) ok,
       sum(t5.act_qty) defective,
       ((sum(t4.act_qty)) - t1.prod_schd_qty) "DIFF(W/OUT DEFECT)"
FROM st_sashizu_all t1,
     st_seizojis_all t2,
     cm_hinmo_all t3,
     st_dekidaka_all t4,
     (SELECT prod_act_no,
             itm_cd,
             sum(act_qty) act_qty
      FROM st_dekidaka_all
      WHERE qual_typ = '0'
      GROUP BY prod_act_no,
               itm_cd) t4,
     (SELECT prod_act_no,
             itm_cd,
             sum(act_qty) act_qty
      FROM st_dekidaka_all
      WHERE qual_typ = '1'
      GROUP BY prod_act_no,
               itm_cd
    ) t5
WHERE 0 = 0
  AND t1.inst_no = t2.inst_no
  AND t2.prod_act_no = t4.prod_act_no (+)
  AND t2.prod_act_no = t5.prod_act_no (+)
  AND t1.itm_cd = t3.itm_cd
  AND t1.itm_cd = t4.itm_cd
  AND t4.ins_ts >= to_date(:qstart_date, 'DDMMYYYY hh24:mi:ss')
  AND t4.ins_ts <= to_date(:qend_date, 'DDMMYYYY hh24:mi:ss')
GROUP BY t1.inst_no,
         t1.itm_cd,
         t3.itm_nm,
         t1.prod_loc_cd,
         t1.bom_ptn,
         t1.prod_schd_qty,
         t1.mld_br_no
ORDER BY 1,
         2,
         3
```

I don't have any idea to fix it, I have tried to make with different ways, but it did not work. Does anyone here can help me to rectify this problem.

Answer (score 3):

It seems to me that you have two aliases named T4.

One is at `,ST_DEKIDAKA_ALL T4,` and the second one at     `(SELECT PROD_ACT_NO, ITM_CD, SUM(ACT_QTY) ACT_QTY  FROM ST_DEKIDAKA_ALL where  QUAL_TYP = '0' GROUP BY PROD_ACT_NO, ITM_CD) T4,(`

Kindly rename one of them, it should work

Comment: I am sorry, finally i did it, and it was going well. I already rectified my query

Comment: Not an issue :)